# Throwable.toString() vs Throwable.getMessage()

Tags: android

I received Throwable in callback function and decided to get more info. I was surprised when `Throwable.getMessage()` brings almost nothing comparing to `Throwable.toString()`:

```
getMessage() - MqttException
toString() - MqttException (0) - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid usage of multi-level wildcard in topic string: dev1/get#
```

Does it means that best practice is to use `Throwable.toString()` instead `Throwable.getMessage()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for the [Throwable Class](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/0f77d250b67ae0678756f986607eb239641dfb9e/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Throwable.java#L4).

You will see that `Throwable.toString()` essentially calls `Throwable.getMessage()` and formats the exception you receive i.e

```
public String toString() {
        String s = getClass().getName();
        String message = getLocalizedMessage();
        return (message != null) ? (s + ": " + message) : s;
    }
```

And from above `getLocalizedMessage();` will make a call to the same function `getMessage()` and append the exception name to the  message returned.

The class also provides an option of `printStackTrace()` that returns exception in this format:

```
Name of the Exception    : Message of the Exception

Stack trace
```

What you decide to use is entirely up to what you feel satisfies your requirement.